# NP-hard problem on planar unit disk graph

Tags: np-hardness, cg.comp-geom

I am curious to know whether there are problems which are np-hard even on planar unit disk graphs.

A unit disk graph is the intersection graph of a collection of unit disks in the plane, where we draw a vertex for each unit disk.

Maybe some problem on a accordingly restricted grid graph?

alex

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you try doing a search for "planar unit disk graphs"? According to [this paper](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~nikolam/downloads/scheduling-adhocnow11.pdf) the problem of finding the largest possible induced matching is NP-complete for planar unit disk graphs, according to [this paper](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=bn0Zub_NpM8C&oi=fnd&pg=PA61) so is the minimum connected dominating set, and according to [this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=4288232&tag=1) so is the maximum number of disjoint dominating sets.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this paper](http://www.utdallas.edu/~ravip/papers/infocom2000.pdf), the dominating set problem and the minimum d-hops dominating set problem are NP-Complete for unit disk graphs.